# Find users without active product

Tags: mysql

I have the following database

```
id | userid | productid | specialid | buydate (timestamp in this sample as YYYY-MM-DD)
1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2020-12-01
2 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 2020-12-25
3 | 3 | 1 | 6 | 2020-12-20
4 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 2020-12-15
5 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 2021-01-15
```

I would like to find out who has an active product.
I want to get all the userid's with the specialid's who bought the product between 2020-12-01 and 2020-12-18, but not from the users who bought the same product more recently.

In this example, this would be ID 1,3,4. userid 2 bought the product during this period, but bought the same product again in January.

Currently I can only come up with the idea to create two arrays in PHP (one with the purchases between 2020-12-01 and 2020-12-18), and one with the purchases between 2020-12-19 and 2021-01-25.
In another loop I could then check if there are matches in the new ones and delete them from the first array.

But isn't there an "easier" way?

Comment: User 3 purchased on `2020-12-20` so they shouldn't be included either, right?

Comment: Oh sorry. My fail. User 3 is newer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this basic table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE data
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    userid INT NOT NULL,
    productid INT NOT NULL,
    specialid INT NOT NULL,
    buydate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO data  VALUES 
(1, 1, 1, 1, '2020-12-01'),
(2, 2, 1, 3, '2020-12-25'),
(3, 3, 1, 6, '2020-12-20'),
(4, 4, 1, 2, '2020-12-15'),
(5, 2, 1, 4, '2021-01-15'),
(7, 2, 1, 4, '2020-12-15');
```

You should be able to write a simple query to handle this for you. The primary query selects your data range, and the sub query excludes more recent ones.

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    data
WHERE
    buydate BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-18'
AND
    NOT userid IN
    (
    SELECT
        userid
    FROM
        data
    WHERE
        buydate > '2020-12-18'
    )
;
```

### This should produce the following result:

| id | userid | productid | specialid | buydate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 2020-12-15 00:00:00 |

Comment: Really Great. Thank you. I will try, but I think that is so great.

Comment: You don't need a subquery here

Comment: @Strawberry, can you either update this without the sub query or post an alternative? The exclusion isn't to just remove more recent orders, but to completely remove users users that also purchased more recenlty. I was in CTE land earlier so maybe my brain isn't firing correctly right now, however.

Comment: At present, no. Your query returns the same result with or without the NOT IN(), so it's hard to know where to go with that.

Comment: It works. Thank you. @Strawberry: Change the Date of ID 2 to 2020-12-15. So the Result is correct

Comment: @Koda you're welcome to edit the question if you think it will make it clearer

Comment: @Strawberry, I have added one more record to the insert that should clarify why the subquery is needed. If you agree, we can just delete this thread.